# Upgrading to G++ 4.8 - exception_ptr.h Does not support exception propagation

Tags: c++, g++, centos6

I'm trying to recompile a huge legacy app with g++ 4.8 in order debug a `glibc detected memory corruption` problem (using AddressSanitizer).  Previously we used g++ 4.4.7.

However, compilation fails with:

`/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/exception_ptr.h:40:4: error: #error This platform does not support exception propagation.`

while compiling a custom exception handler (I guess). The custom exception handler uses `exception_ptr` in only one place:

```
void reportOtherException(void) const
{
    std::exception_ptr p = std::current_exception();
    std::string s = (p != 0 ? p.__cxa_exception_type()->name() : "null");

    printf("DvMain Bad Exception: '%s'\n", s.c_str());
    mErrorReporter(0, DvLog::WARNING, 0, Dv::NO_PROFILE, 0, DvLog::UNHANDLED_OTHER_EXCEPTION);
}
```

And `reportOtherException()` is used like this:

```
try
{
    // Catch and log uncaught exceptions, then exit.
    catch (const std::bad_exception& e) { exHandler.reportBadException(e);      }
    catch (const std::exception& e)     { exHandler.reportStandardException(e); }
    catch (...)                         { exHandler.reportOtherException();     }
}
```

I'm pretty new to C++ and don't know what the error even means. Worked with 4.4.7 and doesn't work with 4.8.

Any pointers on what needs to be changed to compile on 4.8?

**EDIT I**

Here's some additional info:

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
```

**Minimum Code**

*DvComDefaultExceptionHandler_test.h*

```
#include "DvCommon.h"
#include "evt/DvEvt.h"
#include "log/DvLog.h"
#include "com/DvComErrorReporter.h"

#include <new>
#include <exception>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <bits/exception_ptr.h>

class DvComDefaultExceptionHandler
{
public:
    DvComDefaultExceptionHandler(const DvComErrorReporter& er) {}
    ~DvComDefaultExceptionHandler() {   }

    void reportOtherException(void) const
    {
        std::exception_ptr p = std::current_exception();
    }

private:

    static const DvComDefaultExceptionHandler*  mpInstance;
};
```

*DvComDefaultExceptionHandler_test.cpp*

```
#include "DvCommon.h"
#include "com/DvComDefaultExceptionHandler_test.h"


// Pointer to the single instance of the DvComDefaultExceptionHandler class.
const DvComDefaultExceptionHandler*
DvComDefaultExceptionHandler::mpInstance = 0;
```

*Compile command and output*

```
g++ -c -g -O0  -DDEBUG -Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wcast-align 
--ftemplate-depth-32 -march=native -ggdb -fPIC -Iinclude -I../../include 
-I../../src -I/usr/include/libxml2 -D_GNU_SOURCE   
-I/mnt/swdevel/DVMon/source_build/ext/ACE -D__ACE_INLINE__ 
-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/qt-3.3/include 
-o DvComDefaultExceptionHandler.o DvComDefaultExceptionHandler_test.cpp
In file included from ../../include/com/DvComDefaultExceptionHandler_test.h:76:0,
                 from DvComDefaultExceptionHandler_test.cpp:13:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/exception_ptr.h:40:4: error: #error This platform does not support exception propagation.
 #  error This platform does not support exception propagation.
```

**EDIT II**

Tracing through the include files comes down to the value of __GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE.  Running this simple program prints '2' as the value for __GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE.

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("__GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE = %d\n", __GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE);
}
```

G++ VERSION:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
```

**EDIT II**

I've tried it with g++ 6.3.1, running on a Centos 7 VM.  Still the same problem.

*Source File - one line only*

```
#include <bits/exception_ptr.h>
```

Compile command:  `g++ -c -o test.o test.cpp`

Comment: I can't reproduce this with DTS 2 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.9. Please amend your post with the `devtoolset-2-gcc-c++` package version, a minimal example (it's probably some set of `#include` directives which triggers this), and the complete compiler command line.

Comment: Did you compile with -std=c++11?

Comment: I've updated for minimum code.  I didn't compile with std=c++11, same flags which worked for 4.4.7

Comment: I've tried again using -std=c++98.  Same result.

Comment: I've edited the question to include info on the value of __GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE, which is the cause of the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, including `<bits/exception_ptr.h>` directly is technically unsupported.  It says so right in the header file.  This worked in GCC 4.4 by more or less by accident.  The C++11 migration of this header file broke it because for namespace reasons, C++98 code cannot use the `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE` macro, and the header does not work anymore.

In GCC 7, this was fixed (again accidentally) as part of this bug:

- [`std::future` broken on armel](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64735)

The trick to include `<bits/exception_ptr.h>` directly should work again in this version.

This means that your options are:

1. Compile your code in C++11 or later mode (C++14 with GCC 6 recommended).
2. Upgrade to DTS 7 with GCC 7 if and when it becomes available, which has the upstream fix which re-enables the C++98 hack.
3. Wrap the use of `std::exception_ptr` in an opaque type, compile its implementation in C++11 or later mode, and keep the rest of the system in C++98 mode.
4. Use another hack, perhaps like this one:

   ```
   #include <exception>
   #ifndef ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE
   # define ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE __GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE
   #endif
   #include <bits/exception_ptr.h>
   ```

   Again, this is completely unsupported, but it should not be any worse than what you have today (with GCC 4.4).

Comment: Thanks!!  I'll try the #4 hack.  I just wanted to run Address Sanitizer and 4.8 is the closest version which has it.  Even from 4.4.7 to 4.8 there are a lot of new errors/warnings to sort out. Moving to C++11 would be a huge job - probably months. It is a quite large app.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your issue using dockerized Centos6, with gcc 4.8.2. After upgrading dev tools to version 6 (gcc 6.3.1), your code compiled without any problem. Try upgrading dev tools using these steps (suggested for testing only):

- add sclo centos6 repository via adding file */etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-sclo.repo* :

  ```
  [testing-devtools]
  name=devtools multiple for CentOS 
  baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/
  gpgcheck=0
  ```
- install devtoolset-6 packages:

  yum install devtoolset-6-binutils devtoolset-6-gcc-c++
- set bash environment to new version:

  scl enable devtoolset-6 bash

Now try recompiling your base example and full source.

*NOTE*: This same repository contains packages for devtoolset-3 and devtoolset-4 also. Very easy to try if ever needed.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  As mentioned on the other question, upgrading devtools didn't work. The instructions only apply to 64-bit and seems no 32-bit repo available (?)

Comment: I created a new Centos 7 64-bit VM. I've tried g++ 4.8, 5.3, and 6.3.1.  All have the same error.  The cpp file now has only one line: `#include <bits/exception_ptr.h>`.  How did you get it to work?

Comment: @Danny This header is not to be included directly. See its contents. Try including <exception> first.